# how to get the cite text inside a quote?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looping over quotes on a page with jQuery and I want to find the cite text within each blockquote, how would I go about doing it?

I'm looping over them like this:

```js
$('.comment_quote').each(function() 
{
  var actual_text = $(this).text();
  var content = $(this).outerHTML();

  if(actual_text.length > showChar) 
  {
    var html = '<span class="morecontent">' + content + '</span><a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a><br />';

    $(this).replaceWith(html);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<blockquote class="comment_quote"><cite>name</cite>the quoted test</blockquote>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).find('cite').text()` should do it, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Yep that was it! For multi-quotes adding first helped my specific case $(this).find('cite').first().text();

Comment: You can alternatively use - `$(this).find('cite:first').text()`

Comment: Interesting, is that faster or better for any reason or just a different way?